# Выполнение скриптов в конфигурации Nginx

Tags: ip, nginx, подсети, perl

В конфигурации nginx в одном из `location` нужно проверять вхождение ip адреса пользователя в одну из нескольких подсетей и, исходя из результата, отдавать ему ту или иную страницу. Сейчас это сделано с помощью регулярок, например:

```
if( $remote_addr !~* (10\.10\.20[0-7]\.*|10\.20\.203\..*) ) {
set $flag 0;
}
if ($flag = 0) {
rewrite ^.* /login last
}
```

Но так делать не очень удобно, потому что есть, например, подсети с диапазоном 10.10.24.1 -  10.10.31.254 - и такую подсеть уже просто так регуляркой не проверишь. Допустим, я напишу функцию на перле, которая будет проверять на вхождение в нужные мне подсети, можно ли как-то вызвать ее в описании `location`, и если можно, то как? Или может быть у nginx есть какие-то штатные средства для таких целей?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этих целей служит модуль [`ngx_http_geo_module`](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_geo_module.html)

```
http {
    geo $flag {
        default        0;
        10.10.200.0/22 1;
        192.168.0.0/24 1;
        44.44.44.44/32 1;
    }

    # ...
    server {
        # ...
        location / {
            # ...
                if ($flag) {
                rewrite ^ /login last;
            }
        }
        location /login/ { 
           # ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ) это как раз то что нужно)